# Using NSNumberFormatter to Display Extremely Large Numbers

Tags: ios, xcode, nsnumberformatter

I'm working on a calculator app for the iPhone.

I've encountered an issue using `NSNumberFormatter` when displaying results of calculations that are greater than 15 digits.

For example, the result of the calculation **111,111,111,111,111 x 2 = 222,222,222,222,222** (correct). However, the result of the calculation **1,111,111,111,111,111 x 2 = 2,222,222,222,220** (wrong!).

Is there a limit to how many digits that can be displayed using `NSNumberFormatter`, or can someone tell me why the calculation result is not displaying correctly??
Thanks in advance!

Sample code:

```
double absResult = fabs(_result);
NSLog(@"_result = %f", _result);
//_result is the result of the calculation that will be placed onto displayLabel below
// _result = 2,222,222,222,222,222 for the calculation 1,111,111,111,111,111 x 2

NSNumberFormatter *displayString = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];

//** Adds zero before decimal point **
[displayString setMinimumIntegerDigits:1];

 [displayString setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
 [displayString setGroupingSeparator:@","];
 [displayString setGroupingSize:3];

[displayString setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[displayString setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
 NSString *resultString = [displayString stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: _result]];
 self.displayLabel.text = resultString;
```

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with `NSNumberFormatter`'s capabilities but only with the precision of `double` floating point numbers. The `double` type uses 8 bytes to store 53 bit of mantissa and 11 bit exponent. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

The 53 bit mantissa is too small to exactly represent 222,222,222,222,222, so the `double` is set to the closest possible representation.

If you want more precision you should try `NSDecimalNumber` which is better suited for a calculator app anyway.